# Memcached "too many open connections"

Tags: ruby, memcached

One of our test machines has started having messages to this effect appearing in the memcached logs:

```
Too many open connections
Too many open connections
Failed to write, and not due to blocking: Broken pipe
Too many open connections
...
```

When telnetting to it I'm seeing the following stats

```
STAT curr_connections 1063
STAT total_connections 1192
STAT connection_structures 1004
```

and our config file is set up to allow a maximum of 1024 connections. This is probably why we're seeing that message.

My question is, why would these connections be building up so much? Do they get cleaned up on their own or are we supposed to do that ourselves? Why would they be left open after a "get" is sent? I can't find any documentation detailing the life-cycle of these connections!

I'm connecting to memcached using a ruby client.

EDIT

Continuing to check stats every few minutes shows that they are changing every few mminutes, and after a while the "curr_connections" stat dropped down to 65.